# Asterisk/PHP - How to get list of call recordings

Tags: php, asterisk, asteriskami

I want to use AMI(Asterisk Manager Interface) to get the list of calls recorded and then get/fetch one of them to be played in my site. What I expect for listing recordings is like this: `asterisk-site-example.com/recordings` and for each one like this: `asterisk-site-example.com/recordings/23`. But I don't know which method should I use to get all recordings and each one separately.

What I have done:

`composer require marcelog/pami`

my code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$options = [
    'host' => '192.168.1.10',
    'scheme' => 'tcp://',
    'port' => 5038,
    'username' => 'admin',
    'secret' => 'admin',
    'connect_timeout' => 30,
    'read_timeout' => 30
];

try {
    $client = new \PAMI\Client\Impl\ClientImpl($options);
    $client->open();

    // What should I do here? Which method should be used?

    $client->close();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die('Ex: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMI does not support Pull/Get of a Monitored call.

See [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+AMI+Actions)

One way for you to be able to list and pull Monitored calls is to either be locally on the box (which I understand you have no access to)

Another way is to create a custom web API, again local to Asterisk, with which you can then communicate. It could be PHP / Python, anything.

A third option that I see, is for the folder where the monitored calls are `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor` to be accessible to your remote box via NFS, so you can then `have` the monitor files and list/read/get them from your remote machine as local files.

But AMI cannot directly (yet) do that.

Comment: YOU MADE MY DAY :) THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0):

There are no tracking for recordings and no access for it via AMI

You can check recording directory directly from PHP. By default it is /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/XXX/

Comment: I don't have direct access. I want to access them from site A to B that here B is issabel.